# How to tell what the size of an image is after removing seams in using OpenCV2 in Python?

Tags: python, canvas, image-scaling, opencv

I am trying to write some code to manipulate the individual images, "frames", from a live video from the webcam in Python using OpenCV2. I am able to manipulate the frames but I have this excess bit of the image along the edges.

Frame:

[image]

I would like the "black areas" to not be in frame so I am wondering how to manipulate the size of the canvas to allow the black areas to not be visible.

What I would like the frame to look like:

[image]

Does anyone know what code I could use to crop the canvas size?

Comment: Are the border's dimensions constant?

Comment: @eldesgraciado, yes. In my code, not displayed here, the images dimensions are 640 by 360 pixels. Not a lot but enough for my webcam and computer to handle without going under 30 fps.

Comment: You could use Python subprocessing call to ImageMagick -trim function to remove any black that touches the sides of the image. See https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=35579

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Python subprocessing call to ImageMagick command line -trim function to remove any black that touches the sides of the image.

See https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=35579

Input:

[image]

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'convert seams1.png -fuzz 0% -background black -define trim:percent-background=0% -trim +repage result.png'
subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

or

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'convert seams1.png -fuzz 0% -background black -define trim:percent-background=0% -trim +repage result.png'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

[image]

Comment: 2 things, 1 I would prefer to just use OpenCV2 and Numpy to solve this problem. 2, I am using Geany to write my code in so I don't use the command prompt to write or run the code.